# Invoking Lambda from VPC with CodePipeline Fails with Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-codepipeline

I have a Lambda that I have created following the example given by the aws docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html), but I am invoking my Lambda from within a VPC and it seems that the CodePipeline never successfully talks to the Lambda (it gets a timeout and never seems to enter the Lambda as CloudWatch has none of my console.logs); this is despite the fact that I have created a CodePipeline Endpoint from within the VPC and associated the private subnet from which I launch the Lambda out to codepipeline.

I can give the Lambda an API Gateway endpoint and fire it manually just fine from Postman; it takes ~1 second to run.  My Cloudwatch logs just have "Task timed out after 20.02 seconds."  I'm not sure what else I can try; what else might prevent CodePipeline from talking to the Lambda?

Comment: That's a timeout from the CodePipeline service trying to call the AWS API to trigger a Lambda invoke action. The fact that the Lambda is configured to run in the VPC, and the fact that you have a CodePipeline endpoint configured in the VPC is irrelevant. CodePipeline never needs to "talk to Lambda" it needs to talk to the AWS API, which is what always triggers a Lambda invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional logging, I discovered that I actually had the VPC set up correctly and that the Lambda was being invoked; the Lambda was failing to get to S3 and was hanging on getting objects.  I created another Endpoint for S3 for the VPC and was able to move passed the initial issue.